Add custom overload to Python method with existing type hints
Is it possible to extend existing type hints for a Python package in my application code (i.e., not touching the upstream type hints) by adding custom overload for a method? (See also repo with minimal reproducible example.)
For instance, take the type hints for pandas.DataFrame.apply defined in pandas-stubs/core/frame.pyi. As defined, they do not allow for the applied function to return a set, like so:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": list("abc"),
        "b": list("def"),
        "c": list("aaa"),
    }
)
print(df.apply(lambda row: set(x for x in row if not pd.isna(x)), axis=1))

With pandas-stubs installed, Pyright reports:
/Users/david/repos/eva/pandas-apply-set/reprex.py
  /Users/david/repos/eva/pandas-apply-set/reprex.py:10:7 - error: No overloads for "apply" match the provided arguments (reportCallIssue)
  /Users/david/repos/eva/pandas-apply-set/reprex.py:10:16 - error: Argument of type "(row: Unknown) -> set[Unknown]" cannot be assigned to parameter "f" of type "(...) -> Series[Any]" in function "apply"
    Type "(row: Unknown) -> set[Unknown]" is not assignable to type "(...) -> Series[Any]"
      Function return type "set[Unknown]" is incompatible with type "Series[Any]"
        "set[Unknown]" is not assignable to "Series[Any]" (reportArgumentType)
2 errors, 0 warnings, 0 informations

But everything is actually fine at run time -- the script prints out:
0       {a, d}
1    {e, a, b}
2    {c, f, a}
dtype: object

So this is likely a bug and the type hints are overly restrictive. Analogous bugs have been reported against the type hints for pandas.Series.apply, concerning both set and frozenset, and fixed.
My question is: is there a way I can extend the existing type hints for DataFrame.apply in my own code, adding an @overload that allows returning set from the applied function?
I know I can override the entirety of frame.pyi by creating a typings/pandas-stubs/core/frame.pyi in my own project, based on a copy of the upstream version, where I'd add set to the union of returned types in the appropriate overload. But that would require keeping the rest of the file in sync with upstream as it changes.
Instead, I'd like to keep using upstream frame.pyi, just extend the type hints for DataFrame.apply in my custom code to allow returning set from the applied function.
The Claude LLM suggests an approach along the following lines:
import typing as t
import pandas as pd

class DataFrameExt(pd.DataFrame):
    @t.overload
    def apply(
        self,
        f: t.Callable[..., set[t.Any]],
        raw: bool = ...,
        result_type: None = ...,
        args: t.Any = ...,
        *,
        axis: t.Literal[1],
        **kwargs: t.Any,
    ) -> pd.Series[t.Any]: ...

pd.DataFrame.apply = DataFrameExt.apply

But this particular version yields errors of its own.
Is it even possible to make it work? Or should I just cast the DataFrame at the .apply call site to a custom unrelated class which has the correct type hint for .apply? Something like:
import typing as t
import pandas as pd

class DataFrameApplyOverride:
    def apply(
        self,
        f: t.Callable[..., set[t.Any]],
        raw: bool = ...,
        result_type: None = ...,
        args: t.Any = ...,
        *,
        axis: t.Literal[1],
        **kwargs: t.Any,
    ) -> pd.Series[t.Any]: ...

# And then, at the call site of .apply:
print(
    t.cast(DataFrameApplyOverride, df).apply(
        lambda row: set(x for x in row if not pd.isna(x)), axis=1
    )
)

As mentioned initially, I've also set up a minimal reproducible example in this repo which includes the code above alongside dependencies for easy experimenting.

This question is similar to: Is it possible to add type annotations to a method outside of my code?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

mypy doesn't accept "extending overloads" like this, but pyright does: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=34ca75f21eaddbb35772a57a84c5248b. I wouldn't use this method in production though, as it seems very fragile even in Pyright. Probably best to confirm with the Pyright maintainers whether this use is intended.

As a frame challenge, rather than trying to modify the type-stub for DataFrame.apply, instead, modify your function so that it returns one of the expected data-types.
from __future__ import annotations

import pandas as pd

from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": list("abc"),
        "b": list("def"),
        "c": list("aaa"),
    }
)

def to_set(row: pd.Series[T]) -> pd.Series[T]:
    return pd.Series(
        data=tuple(set(x for x in row if not pd.isna(x))),
        dtype=row.dtype,
        name=row.name,
    )

print(df.apply(to_set, axis=1))


I was about to suggest the same thing to the colleague of mine whose code prompted this question, but in the original code, subsequent processing relies on actual sets being stored in the resulting data frame column (they're then aggregated using set.union) :) In general -- yes, the code could be refactored to avoid the issue, but even beyond this specific example, I'm generally interested in whether it's possible to extend existing type hints in the way I've described.
